# how to trigger Picker only by clicking drop-down icon

Tags: react-native

I am using < Picker > from native-base.For now, Items get shown by either clicking the row field(first item) or drop-down icon.
Is there any way to show items ONLY when user clicks on drop-down arrow icon ? I have tried using onTouchEnd with < Picker.Items >  to implement logic but apparently, there is no such property for < Picker.Items >. Any help will be appreciated.